# Mysql statement is having syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running below the MYSQL query and getting this error. Can someone help me here? I am using xampp to run MySQL and executing the statement

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
> DeliveryMode varchar NOT NULL,
> Qty int NOT NULL,
> Spicy ' at line 6

**Below is my create table query**

```
CREATE TABLE Bag (
    BagId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DishName varchar NOT NULL,
    DeliveryMode varchar NOT NULL,
    Qty int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    Spicy varchar(20) NULL,
    SpecialInstructionsFood varchar(250),
    BagStatus varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    DateCreated datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    DateUpdated datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    FOREIGN KEY(DishName) REFERENCES Dish(DishName),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DishName_Bag FOREIGN KEY(DishName)
    REFERENCES Dish(DishName),
    FOREIGN KEY(DeliveryMode) REFERENCES DeliveryModeType(Name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DeliveryModeType_Bag FOREIGN KEY(DeliveryMode)
    REFERENCES DeliveryModeType(Name),
    FOREIGN KEY(Spicy) REFERENCES SpicyType(Name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SpicyType_Bag FOREIGN KEY(Spicy)
    REFERENCES SpicyType(Name),
    FOREIGN KEY(BagStatus) REFERENCES BagStatusType(Name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BagStatusType_Bag FOREIGN KEY(BagStatus)
    REFERENCES BagStatusType(Name),
    PRIMARY KEY (BagId)
);
```

Comment: 'CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html , you need to provide length for dishname and deliverymode if still failing add your FK reference tables.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a `varchar` in mysql you must provide the max length that it supports.

So modify your columns(`DishName` & `DeliveryMode`) which uses `varchar` as datatype to something like `varchar(50)` whichever suits them.

```
DishName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
DeliveryMode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

Comment: I dont think it allowed me, because its a foreign key define in the sql statement

Comment: Use the same data type with same length that is defined in the foreign table for both of the fields. If you're using their primary_key(if integer) then change the datatype in same manner.

Comment: _"I dont think it allowed me ..."_ means you haven't test it yet @AsifAliKhan ?

Comment: Your solution didnt worked @JitendraYadav . But i got the solution now, Actually I was trying to refer to a table in which the primary key was not declared.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Bag (
    BagId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DishName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    DeliveryMode varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    Qty int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    Spicy varchar(20),
    SpecialInstructionsFood varchar(250),
    BagStatus varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    DateCreated datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    DateUpdated datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    FOREIGN KEY(DishName) REFERENCES Dish(DishName),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DishName_Bag FOREIGN KEY(DishName)
    REFERENCES Dish(DishName),
    FOREIGN KEY(DeliveryMode) REFERENCES DeliveryModeType(Name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DeliveryModeType_Bag FOREIGN KEY(DeliveryMode)
    REFERENCES DeliveryModeType(Name),
    FOREIGN KEY(Spicy) REFERENCES SpicyType(Name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SpicyType_Bag FOREIGN KEY(Spicy)
    REFERENCES SpicyType(Name),
    FOREIGN KEY(BagStatus) REFERENCES BagStatusType(Name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BagStatusType_Bag FOREIGN KEY(BagStatus)
    REFERENCES BagStatusType(Name),
    PRIMARY KEY (BagId)
);
```

Comment: does this answer provides some more info than the existing one? If so, it would be great if you can a  little explanation for that.

Comment: Hi Ankit, I dont think adding max length will fix it, because those variables are foreign key that is defined below in the mysql syntax. I think there is some other issue.